# listview layout returns null views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-listview, android-adapter

I'm trying to make a list view that has multiple layouts. The layout is picked by a number 0-5. So I have 6 possible layouts.  I use a switch case to inflate the layout corresponding to the number. I'm having a few problems. First im getting duplicates of certain layouts,those layouts have the values from previous layouts and shouldn't even be there. Another problem with the code below is if i scroll to the buttom the last element has a layout of case 4, then when i scroll to the top and back to the buttom it has a layout from a different case. Why is this happening. Also if i try to set a textview using settext() i get a error saying the textview is null.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder1 = null;
    View v = convertView;

    q = getItemViewType(getType(type, position));

    if (v == null) {
        holder1 = new ViewHolder();

        switch (q) {
            case 0:
                v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout0, parent, false);
                holder1.mainpic = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.mainimage0);
                holder1.string = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.string0);
                holder1.string2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.string_two0);
                break;
            case 1:
                v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout1, parent, false);
                holder1.mainpic = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.mainimage1);
                holder1.string = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.string1);
                break;
            case 2:
                v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout2, parent, false);
                holder1.mainpic = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.mainimage2);
                holder1.string = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.string2);
                break;
            case 3:
                v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout3, parent, false);
                holder1.mainpic = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.mainimage3);
                holder1.string = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.string3);
                break;
            case 4:
                v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout4, parent, false);
                holder1.mainpic = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.mainimage4);
                holder1.string = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.string4);
                break;
            default:
                v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout5, parent, false);
                holder1.mainpic = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.mainimage5);
                holder1.string = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.string5);
                break;
        }

        v.setTag(holder1);
    } else {
        holder1 = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }

    ///holder1.string.settext(" some text")   error

    return v;
}











@Override
public int getItemViewType(int value) {

int type;
if(value ==0)
{
    type=0;
}

else if(value ==1)
{
    type=1;
}else if(value ==2)
{
    type=2;
}
else if(value ==3)
{
    type=3;
}
else if(value ==4)
{
    type=4;
}else
{
    type=5;
}



return type;
```

}

Comment: You should touch up your code some. It's a bit hard to read with all the whitespace and abnormal indents

Comment: codeMagic-ok i cleaned it up a bit

Comment: check to make sure the getCount() method is returning the number of items.

Answer (score 1):

After cleaning up your code, it's clear you had some stray code assigning your `string` view (awful name for a view, btw) two times:

```
holder1.string = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.string0);
holder1.string = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.string_two0);
```

One of these is probably wrong.

Comment: no thats not the problem. I had to change my code a bit before i put it online. Thats why i have bad names

Comment: Hmm, well I'd probably also recommend posting your code for getItemViewType() and getViewTypeCount(). And double-checking that all of your layouts actually have the view IDs you're looking for.

Comment: @kcoppock- i have checked my layouts to make sure all the Ids are there. And i posted my getitemViewType

Comment: Add some logging after each of the `holder.string` assignments in your switch case -- see if any of them are null after the `findViewById()` call.

Comment: @kcoppock- i tried some logging " if(holder.string==null) log.d("","null")" the view is not null.